# Нет доступа к диску С

Tags: windows, windows-10, диск, youtrack

[image: Вот что выдаётся]

Скачивал Youtrack, поставил в опциях(куда его установить) корень С. Установил. Теперь вот такая ошибка, как на картинке. Пытался через безопасный режим вернуть себе права вернуть, но они у меня и не уходили. Удалил пользователя, который был создан ютреком, но всё равно. Что делать, кроме как переустанавливать винду или нести в сервисный центр? Примечательно, кстати, то, что в безопасном режиме диск С нормально отображается(т.е, показывается шкала того, насколько заполнен диск, и количество памяти в нём).

Comment: Управление компьютером -> Управление дисками что говорит?

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, всё ли у вас так:

**Система - Полный доступ**

[image: 1]

**Администраторы - Полный доступ**

[image: 2]

**Пользователи - Чтение и выполнение**

[image: 3]

Попробуйте разные варианты смены разрешений - вот [инструкции](https://derudo.ru/kak-ubrat-zamok-s-papki-windows-7.html).